# How to parse XML when the parent name and child name are equal

Tags: c#, xml

```
  <AR-PACKAGE>
   <Sub-Elements>
      <Imp-Data-Elements>
        <Sub-Elements>
          <Imp-Data-Elements>
            <Sub-Elements>
              <Imp-Data-Elements>
                <Sub-Elements>
                  <Imp-Data-Elements>
                    <Sub-Elements>
                    </Sub-Elements>
                  </Imp-Data-Elements>
                </Sub-Elements>
              </Imp-Data-Elements>
            </Sub-Elements>
          </Imp-Data-Elements>
        </Sub-Elements>
      </Imp-Data-Elements>
    </Sub-Elements>
   </AR-PACKAGE>
```

Currently I am using the below code to parse the xml to a dataset. But when the child element has the same name as parent it throws an error, otherwise it works fine.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filepath); 
reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
reader.MoveToContent();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "AR-PACKAGE")
    {
        XmlReader r = reader.ReadSubtree();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet("tbl");

        ds.ReadXml(r)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your xml does not hold any value, only just elements. What do you want to parse?

Comment: "it throws error" - would be interesting to know *which* exception is thrown.

Comment: Check to make sure Subtree is not null before reading./

Comment: This XML does not correspond to a `DataSet`.  The XML for a `DataSet` would look like the XML shown in https://www.dotnetperls.com/dataset: a root element containing repeating elements corresponding to table rows, where the element name is the table name.  Your XML of arbitrary depth does not fit that pattern.  Why are you trying to read that into a `DataSet` instead of an `XElement` or a custom [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)?